# При вставке в таблицу использую имя переменной INSERT INTO @_name + 'Review' VALUES... , @_name выделен красным

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE procedure AddReview
@id int,
@userName varchar(100),
@dateReview date,
@evaluation int,
@description varchar(500)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @_name varchar(50)
        SELECT @_name = _name
        FROM Fer
        WHERE id = @id
        INSERT INTO @_name + 'Review' VALUES (@username, @dateReview, @evaluation, @description)        

        COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK
    END CATCH
```

Comment: Имя таблицы в запросе должно быть задано фиксированно, использование для этой цели переменных и выражений не допусается. Если надо конструировать имя таблицы динамически, то создавайте запрос целиком в текстовой переменной и выполняйте с помощью sp_executesql

Comment: DECLARE @sql varchar(max) =
  'INSERT INTO '+@_name+'Review VALUES('+@userName+',' +@dateReview+','+@evaluation+',' +@description+ ')'

Comment: вот с параметрами в values поосторожнее, они же будут просто текстом идти и если они текстовые, они должны быть заключены в кавычки. я бы предложил посмотреть как параметры передавать в sp_executesql